# carousel AngularJs modify BG

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i'm working on a single page application.

do acomplish a small part of this i need a modified carousel.
at the moment i have. this Js and HTML. 
at the this moment i would like to know something simple i think.

**i would like to change the kitten background to whatever that works. (1 static image)**

*i will be placing textboxes on the carousel slides <- is this possible to save the data like some sort of powerpoint ? if any have a quik think around that would be nice but the BG porbleme is what i need fixed at the time, thanks in advance*

*to save the data i work with a server(azure) if this is of any importance for answering*

> ```
> .controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
>     var slides = $scope.slides = [];
>     $scope.addSlide = function () {
>         var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
>         slides.push({
>             image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
>             text: ['More', 'Extra', 'Lots of', 'Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
>               ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
>         });
>     };
>     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>         $scope.addSlide();
>     }
> })
> ```

```
<section>
  <div>
      <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
          <div style="height: 305px">
              <carousel interval="myInterval">
                  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                          <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                      </div>
                  </slide>
              </carousel>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script src="/presentation/js/presentation.js"></script>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image: 'http://www.woblogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/grey-pattern-bg.jpg',
                text: ['More', 'Extra', 'Lots of', 'Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
                  ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]

image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + **'/300',**
        text: ['More', 'Extra', 'Lots of', 'Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
          ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
```